# PythonNet: How to notify c# caller from python function when embedded in c#

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I'm embedding pythonnet in c# now. When I'm calling a long time consuming python function, I want the python function notify the process to c# caller, how can I do this?

Environment:
Python 3.6, C#

Example:

C# code

```
public class TestCallback
{
    public void CheckingProcess(int step)
    {
        //do some notify
    }

    public void CallPython()
    {
       using (Py.GIL())
       {
            long_time_worker(CheckingProcess);
       }
    }
}
```

Python code

```
def long_time_worker(callback):
    'callback: c# function'

    for i in range(1000):
        #do some work.......
        callable(i)  #notify current step to caller
```

Comment: Use Pipes. Try passing log messages from python code to C# code via pipes. Its simple and neat. I can provide code snippet if required.